# How to recover formula cell cache result from excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to retrieve the cached result of a formula cell in excel, the entire column is comprised of formula cells and i want to store the cached results of the columns' cells in an arraylist, but i get the error.
Apologies, i pasted the wrong code earlier, its fixed now.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String filename = "C:/Users/L30902/Desktop/eclipse folder/FeaturesTest/student.xlsx";
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    int cellvalue = 0;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator rowIter = sheet.rowIterator();

        while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
            XSSFRow myRow = (XSSFRow) rowIter.next();
            Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
            Vector<String> cellStoreVector = new Vector<String>();
            while (cellIter.hasNext()) {
                XSSFCell myCell = (XSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                try {
                    cellvalue = myCell.getCachedFormulaResultType();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                cellStoreVector.addElement(Integer.toString(cellvalue));
            }
            String secondcolumnValue = null;

            int i = 0;
            secondcolumnValue = cellStoreVector.get(i).toString();

            insertQuery(secondcolumnValue);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
    }
    // showExelData(sheetData);
}

private static void insertQuery(String secondcolumnvalue) {
    System.out.println(secondcolumnvalue);
}
```

I should return values like 500, 33 but i only return 0, 0

Comment: The full stacktrace would be useful.

Comment: The code posted doesn't seem to have anything to do with the stacktrace posted - can you correct them to match?

Comment: Why are you saving the *type* of the evaluated cell, as opposed to the *value*?